# AngularFire/Firebase - AuthGuard unresolved function or method map()

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire, angularfire2

Trying to implement canActivate for my routes. Login and connections to firebase are fine but I tried using this code below for canActivate and I keep getting the error about unresolved function or method map(). I have made sure everything is imported correctly.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
}

canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
return this.afAuth.authState
  .take(1)
  .map(authState => !!authState)
  .do(authenticated => {
    if (!authenticated) {
      this.router.navigate([ '/error' ]);
    }
  });
 }
}
```

AuthService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user = firebaseAuth.authState;
  }

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    this.firebaseAuth
      .auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(value => {
        console.log('Logged in!');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error while logging in!', err.message);
      });
  }

  logout() {
    this.firebaseAuth.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

Comment: did you correctly registered in your `app.module.ts`?

Comment: AuthGuard is in providers array.

Comment: your code looks ok to me, check this [page](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/282) .

Answer (score 0):

One thing i noticed you need to return true or false to a Boolean function

try this

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
return this.afAuth.authState
  .take(1)
  .map(authState => !!authState)
  .do(authenticated => !authenticated ? this.router.navigate(['/error']) : true);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you + AngularFire are importing Observable from `rxjs/Observable` rather than 'rxjs/Rx' to reduce bundle size, you need to also import the RxJS operators you want to use.

`import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`